# SSL Error / RSA premaster secret error

Tags: apache, ssl, paypal, ssl-certificate, lamp

anyone know what is the problem regarding the error that encountered in the PayPal sandbox?

It was working fine for months last time and we changed our server and IPN stopped working. We are not sure is PayPal issue or our issue.

In the web server access log there's no entry of the PayPal IPN POST log shown up and we can't figure out what is the problem.

> IPN Delivery Failed:I/O error: RSA premaster secret error; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLKeyException: RSA premaster secret error

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/ipn_simulator

[image]

---

**Extra info :** 
We are using two different sub domain with two SSL certificate in a single IP.

***Example :***

https://www.example.com/ - For main website (SSL cert A)

https://ipn.example.com/ - For PayPal IPN (SSL cert B)

```
<VirtualHost x.x.x.x:443>
    ServerName ipn.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/path/to/ipn.example"

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "/path/to/ipn_example_com.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/path/to/ipn_example_com.key"
    SSLCertificateChainFile "/path/to/CA1.pem"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost x.x.x.x:443>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
    DocumentRoot "/path/to/www.example"

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "/path/to/www_example_com.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/path/to/www_example_com.key"
    SSLCertificateChainFile "/path/to/CA2.pem"
</VirtualHost>
```

x.x.x.x is an IP address (Both IP is the same)

Comment: Do you know which version of Java the client is using?

Comment: I don't think it's related to your problem, but if it's not using Java 7 at least, it may have problems to connect to your server. You're using SNI (two certs, same IP address/port) on your server, and that's only supported since Java 7.

Answer (score 2):

I have run into the same problem and it seems as if the IPN Simulator is unable to handle https properly. (or perhaps it has trouble with RSA keys over 1024 bits?) I am unable to use the simulator, but if I test everything (in the sandbox) using a Paypal business / consumer accounts and fake a purchase, I do get IPN messages sent to my handler.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to set the environment variable JAVA_EXT_DIRS which value would be the path to [..]jre\lib\ext

The accepted answer of [SunTlsRsaPremasterSecret KeyGenerator not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872520/suntlsrsapremastersecret-keygenerator-not-available) might be of some help

Other related posts which can be found on the web:

http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?78991-plm-in-4-x-javax-net-ssl-SSLKeyException-RSA-premaster-secret-error

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SMX4-537

Comment: Could you open a ticket / issue with PayPal customer service?